# Retry step in waterfall dialog

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm working on a dialog where the user have to enter some different data. The data needs to be valid before the user can continue to next step.

I'm using a waterfall dialog and after each step I have some validation. If the validation fails the user needs to be reprompted (up to 3 times) with the previous step.

As I see it I have two options: 1) building many steps into a waterfall dialog and using next if the validation passes or 2) building a pretty complex subset of dialogs that each can do a replace dialog of themselfes if the validation fails.

Any alternatives and better approaches are welcome :)

I'm using SDK 4.0 preview.

Comment: What language are you using and what kind of validation do you want to provide?

Comment: I'm using C#. Validation is based on some business rules and uses a lookup in a database - validating company information etc.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with C#, but you can add a [custom validator](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Internal/TextPromptInternal.cs#L65) to your prompt so that you don't need to add multiple waterfall steps just to conduct one prompt. I'm not sure of the mechanics in the C# SDK, but to start with, you just need to `return undefined` in the JS SDK to get the user to be reprompted.

Comment: Not sure if this will be able to help a lot, but here's an example in JS of providing a custom validator. If the validation fails, the bot will reprompt the user. [`'namePrompt'`](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/samples/multiple-prompts-bot-es6/bot.js#L7L14)

Comment: do you find a way to do that?